# DIV around a centered image

Tags: html, css

I am trying to display an image, centered vertically and horizontally on a screen (which in my case, is a modal screen). The image must be a maximum of 80% high, and 80% wide. It can be landscape, square or portrait.

I have achieved that. But now I need to add a div, fitted tightly around the image, so that I can apply a text-over effect.

This is what I have so far.

https://jsfiddle.net/Cralis/1w8d4zx5/

```
<div class="imageContainer">
    <img id="imgContainer" class="fullimage animated fadeIn" src="http://cameraflare.com/photostore/23d255d8-e259-47ee-be2d-fae68c730f6d/afda43dd-5a81-40b2-8161-d1f222689d3f.jpg">
    <h2>
              <span>The one and only:
                <span class='spacer'></span>
                <br />
                <span class='spacer'></span>
                The Hulk
                </span>
                </h2>
  </div>
```

I am trying to achieve what this tutorial shows, except, their demo is aligned left on the screen. My image is centered.

https://css-tricks.com/text-blocks-over-image/

How can I get the imageContainer div to 'hug' the image?

Comment: What about this https://jsfiddle.net/1w8d4zx5/1/?

Comment: That does it, but my image is no longer centered. How can I keep the image vertically and horizontally centered on the screen?

Comment: @Craig I'm added an answer below,please check it

Answer (score 0):

Not pretty sure but i think what you are looking for is the following:

- Set your `.imageContainer` as `display: inline-block` and add it `text-align: left`
- Set the parent of image container to `text-align: center`

So you will get your div centered but you will also wrap/hug the image with the border. Take a look here:

https://jsfiddle.net/0k3wrfxt/

Comment: This nearly works, but I must have something interfering, because the box with the image is left aligned, even though in your example - it's centered.

Comment: @Craig you need to set your `#PhotoDisplaySection` to `text-align: center`

Answer (score 0):

you can use **css3 flexbox** concept to achieve this. 
add the following styles to the parent container of your image

- display:flex;
- align-items:center;
- justify-content:center;

and remove the **margin:100px;** on your **.imageContainer** ,it will work fine .I'm added the snippet below.

```css
html,body{
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
  justify-content:center;
  
  }
.fullimage {
  vertical-align: top;
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
  border-radius: 7px;
}

.imageContainer {
  max-height: 80vh;
  max-width: 80vw;
  border: solid;
  /*margin: auto;
  margin-left:100px;*/
  position: absolute;
  padding: 0;
}

h2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 200px;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

h2 span {
  color: white;
  font: bold 24px/45px Helvetica, Sans-Serif;
  letter-spacing: -1px;
  background: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  /* fallback color */
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  padding: 10px;
}

h2 span.spacer {
  padding: 0 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="imageContainer">
    <img id="imgContainer" class="fullimage animated fadeIn" src="http://cameraflare.com/photostore/23d255d8-e259-47ee-be2d-fae68c730f6d/afda43dd-5a81-40b2-8161-d1f222689d3f.jpg">
    <h2>
              <span>The one and only:
                <span class='spacer'></span>
                <br />
                <span class='spacer'></span>
                The Hulk
                </span>
                </h2>
  </div>
```